# If OWF were to exist, do we know for sure that one of the candidate OWF would indeed be a OWF?

Tags: one-way-function, complexity

We have several candidates for OWF, like multiplication/factoring and discrete exponencial/logarithm. What I am asking is:

Does the existence of one way functions imply that our candidate functions are indeed one way functions?

Is there a candidate one way function whose one wayness is directly tied to the existance of OWF?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you are looking for the notion of a *universal one-way function*.
[Rafael Pass/abhi shelat's notes](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6830/2009fa/lecnotes.pdf) contain a construction on page 49. The construction is "unnatural" in the sense that it involves parsing the input to the OWF $y$ as a pair $\langle M\rangle || x$, where $\langle M\rangle$ is interpreted as the description of a Turing machine. Then you simulate $M(x)$'s executation for a bounded number of steps.

This is fairly typical of "universal" constructions (others exist, namely Levin's universal search). It is far from being feasible in practice though.
The notes mention that a "natural" universal OWF construction is a very open problem (circa 2008-ish).